# Does Ionic 6 app support Android overscroll effects?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Let say I have the following code and the app is running on Android:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>1</ion-item>
  <ion-item>2</ion-item>
  <ion-item>3</ion-item>
  <ion-item>4</ion-item>
  <ion-item>5</ion-item>
  <ion-item>6</ion-item>
  <ion-item>7</ion-item>
  <ion-item>8</ion-item>
  <ion-item>9</ion-item>
  <ion-item>10</ion-item>
<ion-content>
```

Scrolling is OK, but when I scroll to the top or bottom, there is no overscroll effect (bounce, stretch or glow) presented at all. How to make the overscroll effects available on my ionic app?

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @EliyaCohen Ionic framework team said it's a Chromium level issue.